# Generate 24 numbers using 1-12, repeating each number only once

Tags: python

This is the code I've written:

```
import random
numberList = []
while len (numberList) != 24:
    number = random.randint (1, 12)
    if numberList.count (number) < 2
        numberList.append (number)
```

My problem with this is the While loop can loop over 100 times before numberList is populated, so very inefficient.

Is there is cleaner, more efficient way to code what I want to do?

Comment: arrray(1,1,2,2,3,3,.....,12), then shuffle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that will work for Python 2 and 3 (`range` is a generator in 3 and has to be manually converted to a `list`):

```
import random

number_list = list(range(1,13)) * 2
random.shuffle(number_list)

print(number_list)
# [9, 5, 11, 6, 3, 4, 9, 7, 4, 6, 3, 11, 1, 
#  12, 8, 10, 7, 2, 1, 8, 2, 5, 10, 12]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import random
my_list = range(1,13)*2
random.shuffle(my_list)
```

Comment: I think this will give a `TypeError` since `*` isn't a supported operand type for `range()` (probably because it's a generator).

Comment: @Alec, it's only a generator in python3, it generates a list in python2

Comment: It depends on python version. For python 3 your answer is correct, but in Python 2 `range` produces a list, rather than a generator.

Comment: Good to know. Will `list(range())` still work in Python 2?

Comment: Yes, but it adds an extra function call which isn't necessary. It also forces the construction of two lists. For example: `r = range(10); id(r) -> some_id; lr = list(r); id(lr) -> some_other_id`

Comment: I should have specified im using Python3

Answer (score 1):

```
reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,[ [i]*2 for i in range(1,13) ])
```

output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of number you already added twice and remove them from your source of numbers. So instead of of having randomint(1, 12) you will need to modify it to randomly pick from list of integers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this maybe the solution:

```
    import numpy as np
    import random

    myArray=np.append((random.sample(range(1,13), 12)),(random.sample(range(1,13), 12)))
    print myArray
```

Comment: range(1,13), not range(12)